# Determine What Text Is Hidden Due To overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, hidden

I've searched but I can't seem to find an answer on how to do this.

I'd like to be able to determine what text is hidden/invisible while using overflow: hidden in a div. I'm trying manage some pagination when the screen is printed.

In the (simplified) example below I'd like to be able to determine what text from div-1 isn't visible so it can be moved to div-2 via javascript or jQuery.

```
// css
.divs {
    width: 250px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}


// html
<div class="divs" id="div-1">
    This is some text that I can see ... 
    but this text is not visible due to overflow: hidden
</div>

<div class="divs" id="div-2"></div>
```

Comment: Without using some sort of convoluted method like wrapping each character in a `<span>` and doing some crazy ninja positioning checks in Javascript, this isn't really possible. You might want to re-think your approach to the entire system here.

Comment: @Aweary, Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no method to determine which text is hidden, which text is shown. You may try to workaround like this: calculate width of text by multiply letter metric (width) with number of character. Then compare with div with, but it not always accurate.

PS: there is another solution here [How to find the last visible word position in a text container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356819/how-to-find-the-last-visible-word-position-in-a-text-container)

Comment: My account is new. I don't have the reputation points to up vote at this time.