# Store text before text-overflow:elipsis?

Tags: css, string, text, overflow, ellipsis

I have a container limited in height, and inside content in a p -tag with a long content and  therefore using text ellipsis and overflow. How can I get the last sentence / word or the entire text which is displayed **before** the ellipsis and store it?

```
.grid-container > div > p {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
    display: -webkit-box;
    max-width: 700px;  
    max-height: 360px;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis-word;
}
```

Comment: How do you intend to store it? Is this a css only question or are you planing on using javascript for this?

Comment: @elitepc both is acceptable for me, even I prefer a css only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a similar question, asking about the same but without the elipsis part. It's not exactly the answer, but it's close enough to it: [How to find the last visible word position in a text container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356819/how-to-find-the-last-visible-word-position-in-a-text-container)